# Is it possible to define anonymous subroutines in a hash constructor in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, coderef

Is it possible to define anonymous subroutines in a hash constructor in Perl?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
my %array = { one   => sub { print "first $_[0]" },
              two   => sub { print "next  $_[0]" },
              three => sub { print "last  $_[0]" }};

$array{$foo}->('thing');
```

But it isn't working.  The code seems to run and compile, but the values in the array are blank.  If I do this:

```
my %array;

$array{'one'}   = sub { print "first $_[0]" };
$array{'two'}   = sub { print "next  $_[0]" };
$array{'three'} = sub { print "last  $_[0]" };

$array{$foo}->('thing');
```

Then it seems to work fine.  So I have a workaround, but it's just bugging me and I wondered if anyone knows whether it's possible and, if so, what the syntax is.

Comment: In perl, they are called hashes, not associative arrays.

Comment: Sorry... I think the edition of the camel book I learned from called them associative arrays.  My bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning into the hash incorrectly.  Using `{}` constructs an anonymous hash reference, which you assign to a scalar.  But you're assigning to a named hash (`%array`).

You need to assign into a scalar:

```
my $array = { one   => sub { print "first $_[0]" },
              two   => sub { print "next  $_[0]" },
              three => sub { print "last  $_[0]" }};

$array->{$foo}->('thing');
```

Or to not use the anon constructor syntax:

```
my %array = ( one   => sub { print "first $_[0]" },
              two   => sub { print "next  $_[0]" },
              three => sub { print "last  $_[0]" });

$array{$foo}->('thing');
```

Comment: Of course, this would even be more correct, if we called that variable %hash instead of %array

Comment: @Manni: Good point.  While hashes are technically also called "associative arrays" in practise every Perl programmer I know uses "array" to mean exclusively plain arrays, and "hash" to mean hashes.

Comment: Ack, I just britishized the word "practice."  I don't know where that came from.

Comment: "practice" is the noun, "practise" the verb.

Comment: So it was not only britishized but ungrammatical.  Here in America, "practice" is both the noun and the verb.

Comment: @Adam: In the English speaking world :P the easy way to remember which is which is to think of advise/advice. License/license, practise/practice et. al. all follow the same rules. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

That's because in the first case, you're creating a hashref not a hash, what you want is:

```
my $array;
$array = { one => ... }; # not %array = { .. };
...
$array->{one}->('thing');
```

Comment: Or just change the brackets to parens and %array can stay a hash, not a ref.

Answer (score 4):

Greg Hewgill is on the right track.  Always enable the `strict` pragma.  Also, always enable warnings--but I recommend against using the -w switch in your code.

Instead, take advantage of the `use warnings` pragma.  That way you can selectively disable particular groups of warnings in lexically scoped areas of your code.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foo('bar');
foo();

sub foo {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';

    my $foo = shift || 'DEFAULT';

    print "Foo is $foo\n";
}
```

Consistent use of the strict and warnings pragmas will save you hours and hours of time.

Answer (score 3):

I spent something like two hours trying to track down this [exact braces-vs-parentheses problem](http://hewgill.com/journal/entries/466-stupid-perl) in a script not too long ago. If you use the `-w` switch to Perl, then you'll get a warning "Reference found where even-sized list expected", which at least gives a clue where to look. Today, all Perl scripts should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
```

Your Perl life will be immeasurably less frustrating.

Comment: I'd recommend use warnings over -w, as the former can be turned off in a lexical scope when needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be parenthesis, not curly braces:

```
my %array = ( one   => sub { print "first $_[0]" },
              two   => sub { print "next  $_[0]" },
              three => sub { print "last  $_[0]" }});
```

'{ a => 1, b => 2 }' produces a reference to a hash.  So the following would also work:

```
my $array = { one   => sub { print "first $_[0]" },
              two   => sub { print "next  $_[0]" },
              three => sub { print "last  $_[0]" }};

$array->{one}->('thing');
```